# How to check the Internet Gateway address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC and public subnet. On that subnet I lunched an EC2 instance with an Elastic IP.

As per AWS, traffic will be redirected via the Internet Gateway.

Will any address translation happen here (without NAT)? Won't it convert the private address to a public address?

If the traffic is going via the Internet Gateway then what would be the IP address?

Comment: Use something like `curl https://checkip.amazonaws.com/` to see what the public IP address being used is.